# php artisan serve does not load, I keep getting this error message

Tags: laravel

```
[ReflectionException]
Class App\Http\Middlware\AgeMiddleware does not exist
```

Each time I get this error because I tried creating a middleware and after it didn't work I decided to delete all its components ant then the error came up

Comment: Because the middleware doesn't exist? Did you remember to remove the call in the Kernal?

Comment: If `App\Http\Middlware\AgeMiddleware.php` exists, try to run `composer du`. If this won't help, show the class, please.

Comment: Thank you very much it worked. I'm new to laravel